# Weight paint gloves problem

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I've a big problem with gloves, I don't know why but It doesn't detect the inside area the weight paint, It only detects the outside area of It, anyway the hand moves good with the outside area of the glove, Idk why It makes that:( Any ideas on how to solve It plss?? PD: The middle "finger" that It's not affected with the weight paint It's not the finger, It's the inside of the glove[image]